# How to fetch the entire rows having even numbers in numpy?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying want to fetch the rows that are having even numbers from the array below:

```
    mat1 = np.array([[23,45,63],[22,78,43],[12,77,47],[53,47,33]]).reshape(4,3)
mat1
array([[23, 45, 63],
       [22, 78, 43],
       [12, 77, 47],
       [53, 47, 33]])
```

And the below code returns only the values..

```
mat1[mat1%2==0]
array([22, 78, 12])
```

Is there any way to fetch the entire row/column having the even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import numpy as np

mat1 = np.array([[23,45,63],[22,78,43],[12,77,47],[53,47,33]])
is_even = (mat1 % 2 == 0)

# Rows
print(mat1[is_even.any(1)])
# [[22 78 43]
#  [12 77 47]]

# Columns
print(mat1[:, is_even.any(0)])
# [[23 45]
#  [22 78]
#  [12 77]
#  [53 47]]
```